# How to return a current form's grand-parent's name (i.e. me.parent.parent.name)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to pass as an argument three parameters (userlanguage,the name of the parent form and the name of the grand-parent form name)
I am able to do the two former but not the latter.

I tried using `Me.Parent.name` to return the name of the parent's form but it doesn't work if it's not attached to a control-

here is a sample:

```
Private Sub btnNoInterruptRational_Click()

    Dim grandParentName As String
    grandParentName = Me.Parent.name


    If (Me.OpenArgs = "English") Then

         DoCmd.OpenForm "frmP2CQ", acNormal, , , acEdit, _
         , "English|" & grandParentName
    End If

    If (Me.OpenArgs = "French") Then

         DoCmd.OpenForm "frmP2CQ", acNormal, , , acEdit, _
         , "French|" & grandParentName
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a form named *frmGrandparent*.  It contains a subform named *frmParent*.  And *frmParent* contains a subform named *fsubColortable*.

I set a break point in the Form Open event of *fsubColortable*.  Then in the Immediate window, examined the `Parent.Name` and `Parent.Parent.Name` properties ...

```vb
? Me.Name
fsubColortable
? Me.Parent.Name
frmParent
? Me.Parent.Parent.Name
frmGrandparent
```

So `Me.Parent.Parent.Name` *can* give you the name of the top-level (grandparent) form.  I don't see why your attempt fails.  I suggest you test a simplified version of your procedure which focuses just on `Parent.Parent.Name` ... leaving out all the other stuff temporarily.

If you still can't get what you want from `Me.Parent.Parent.Name` in that simple version, give us details (such as error message) so we can figure out why it fails.

And if the simple version works correctly, the problem is about how you're using `Me.Parent.Parent.Name` in the original version.  More specific details about the nature of the problem there should help.

Comment: Hi, first of all, i appreciate your detailed comment and I will go ahead and test a simpler version, however, before I do that, I just want to clarify one thing with you, when you mention in your comment: "it contains a subform named frmParent", do you actually mean a master-detail relationship design- or  'subform' is used loosely here to mean another form which will be called from 'frmParentForm'? i am asking that is i want to clear up the possible obvious first.Also, the error I get is" the expression you entered has an invalid reference to the parent property. i'm using MS Access 2013,btw.

Comment: I don't understand that question.  Are you perhaps talking about what Access calls a "subdatasheet"?  My subforms are both actual saved form objects.

Comment: Yes, we are on the same page, I am talkng about  multiple actual save form objects, as you put and not "subdatasheet".it just at times, it is also referred as subform, so i wanted to clarify with you we are talking about the same MS Access object. thanks

Comment: Hi, again, i've done more research, and it was mentioned that the property of parent.name cannot be referenced just simply by a form using DoCmd.OpenForm "frmName"- and this is how i open all my object forms and that's why i am getting the reference error- so i'm wondering what's the alternative/other option to open a form- here is the quote "You use Parent from a *subform* to refer to the calling form.You can't
use Parent when the two forms are only related by the fact that one of
them has opened the other one with DoCmd.OpenForm." ref:http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/use-parent-t2466637.html

Comment: I'm more confused now.  When one form calls `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open a second form, that second form is not a subform of the first form.  Is that what you're talking about?  In that situation, the `Parent` property is not available because neither of the 2 forms is a subform.

Comment: yes, that's what i am talking about- so i guess i don't know how to make a subform-so how do you make a subform from another form? that's why i went over the semantics with you earlier to be sure I understood well the 'subform' terminology- because like i said- i see 'subform' used as master-detail form context in many books- and i am not referring to that- I just have to independent form and i want one to call another one-and know who is calling who?

Comment: A subform is just a form which is contained in a subform control on another form.  So, in that situation, when you open the containing form, the form in the subform control also opens automatically.  When you open a form directly with `DoCmd.OpenForm`, it does not know which form called `DoCmd.OpenForm`.  In fact, it doesn't even know what method was used to open it.  If you want to communicate that information to the target form, use the *OpenArgs* option with `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

Comment: thanks for confirming. this is what i started to do, passing three arguments (userlanguage, grandParentFormName,parentFormName) with OpenArgs and parsing them one by one on the receiving form. Thanks for sticking with me on this ride.

Answer (score -1):

It would seem like you need to close that OpenArgs.  For instance:

```
     DoCmd.OpenForm "frmP2CQ", acNormal, , , acEdit, _
     , "French|" & grandParentName
```

should be

```
     DoCmd.OpenForm "frmP2CQ", acNormal, , , acEdit, _
     , "French|" & grandParentName & ""
```

Comment: There may well be a difference between a string and the same string concatenated with an empty string, but I'm struggling to grasp it - can you elaborate?

Comment: Access can be fickle, that's all I know.  I just don't have time to list all the cases where you have to do something strange to make Access happy.  :o)